# Cannot add another set to sets in Office Add in manifest

Tags: javascript, azure, single-sign-on, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am building Outlook Web Add-in and since I want to get the access token I am using [this reference article](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync) but trying to add this IdentityApi set to my manifest:

```
...
<Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
      <Set Name="IdentityAPI" MinVersion="1.1" /> 
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
...
```

cannot start the add-in and I'm given this error:

> Failed to deploy the manifest file to the Exchange server.  This app can't be installed. The Requirements element can only include one Set element. The name of the Set element must be 'Mailbox'

Why?

Comment: In the article you mentioned, "In Outlook, this API is not supported if the add-in is loaded in an Outlook.com or Gmail mailbox."

Comment: But then how to get Access Token when I have Outlook WEB add-in?